# Tampermonkey script to edit links in source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink, tampermonkey

I've recently started working at a company as a student where the workload is minimal. Many of the jobs they do manually, I can solve with a simple script, thus giving me loads of free time.

The downside to this is my account does not have internet access outside the website relevant to my workplace. I've been sniffing around and notice their redirect proxy server has a really amateurish system to block websites, it basically scans the web address and looks for certain keywords. By simply adding `?google` to a web address, I can access it without issue.

But, every single link has to be edited with "?google" at the end, which is not really efficient. 
So I'm looking to write a script that looks up links (CSS/JS/Pictures/etc..) and automatically adds `?google` at the end.

For example:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=4a57bb936dd5
```

would become:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=4a57bb936dd5?google
```

Since I haven't worked yet with Tampermonkey yet I wonder if anyone knows a simple and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Don't put your answer in the question. Make an answer post instead. See ["Can I answer my own question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I had to wait 8 hours cause it's a new account :(

Answer (score 1):

Well after fiddling a bit I managed to write a script, here's the code if anyone's interested.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Google Add
// @namespace     
// @description   
// @include       *
// ==/UserScript==

var srcs = document.links;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");


for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    links[i].href = links[i].href+'?google';        
}

for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++ ) {
    scripts[i].src = scripts[i].src+'?google'; 
}

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
    imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src+'?google'; 
}

for (i=0; i<srcs.length; i++)
{
    srcs[i].href = srcs[i].href+'?google';
}

for (i=0; i<iframes.length; i++){

    iframes[i].src = iframes[i].src+'?google'; 
}
```